# How to select all the rows 'IN' a list of values with NULL in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**(IMPORTANT: I don't know the list of values, the IN values is a parameter.. )**

I want to select all the rows in a table using IN, that values are of type varchar but maybe had null values, how can I query all rows including the null value?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN('Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov', null)
```

This query will return Paul or Daniel or Yakov, but never returns the rows with the name null.

A solution maybe make an union:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN('Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov', null)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN(??????)
```

With ?????? I'm meaning WHAT I NEED TO PUT THERE TO SELECT THE NULLS?

Can you help?, thanks.

IMPORTANT: How can I check the null value is present in the IN list?

Comment: What type of parameter you pass-array or variable ? You can pass value without null or remove those variable that is null and then use manually OR name IS NULL

Answer (score 2):

This query will return Paul or Daniel or Yakov or the rows with the name null. Something `=` or `IN` null will always return null. So you have to use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE name IN('Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov') 
OR name IS NULL
```

For parameter send null differently.

```
DECLARE @params AS VARCHAR(20) = '''Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov'''
DECLARE @willNULLShow AS BIT = 1

DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(400)

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN '+ @params
IF @willNULLShow = 1
BEGIN
    SET @Query = @Query + ' OR name IS NULL'
END
```

Comment: Are you using dynamic query ??

Comment: yes is dynamic with PDO in php, but php and PDO is not important for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Remember that in the documentation of `CONCAT` in MySQL says:
**`CONCAT`() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.**

```
SELECT * FROM  people 
    WHERE (IF (CONCAT( 'Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov', null  ) IS NULL, 
         name IS NULL, name IN( 'Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov', null ) )) 
        OR name IN('Paul', 'Daniel', 'Yakov', null)
```

IF name IS NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM  people 
    WHERE (IF (CONCAT( null  ) IS NULL, 
         name IS NULL, name IN( null ) )) 
        OR name IN(null)
```

IF name is 'Paul':

```
SELECT * FROM  people 
    WHERE (IF (CONCAT( 'Paul'  ) IS NULL, 
         name IS NULL, name IN( 'Paul' ) )) 
        OR name IN('Paul')
```

What do you think?

What I really want is to use this query in PHP using PDO like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  people 
        WHERE (IF (CONCAT( :name  ) IS NULL, 
             name IS NULL, name IN( :name ) )) 
            OR name IN(:name)";

$stmt->bindParam( "name", "Paul" );

//or

$stmt->bindParam( "name", null );
```

Comment: I don't get it.. how it differs from my answer.

Comment: If you want to show all null names and `param` names you could just do as @Prdp or my first query says.

Comment: All I can see is you are doing so many unwanted things in your query

Comment: Me too now :'( because, I'm thinking to query the table from php binding the parameter with `('a,b,c,d')`, but now I think the values will be binded as `'a,b,c,d'` and not as `'a','b','c',d'`... :'(

Comment: but this query works with only one value: if the value is 'Paul' works or the value is NULL works.. not for multiple values binded